# What type of chemical reaction is sulfuric acid with calcium carbonate?

Tags: terminology

$$\ce{H2SO4 + CaCO3 -> H2CO3 + CaSO4}$$

I thought it would be a **double replacement** and also a **decomposition** reaction because $\ce{H2CO3}$ immediately breaks down to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: The decomposition part is not portrayed in your equation so you can't say that the equation contains decomposition.

Answer (score 3):

While *double replacement* is correct, you could also classify it as a *neutralization* reaction (what I think would be the most common answer if one had to pick a single description).  I agree with the comment explaining that you can't consider it a *decomposition* reaction as written.  You would need to explicitly show that as part of the reaction for that to be an acceptable description.